# FastAPI code updates not reflected instantly in docker container

Tags: python, docker, fastapi

I am running FastAPI web app in the docker container on the ubuntu server. I have configured gitlab pipeline - each commit triggers the pipeline - new image is build, old container is removed and the new one is started.
However, the committed updates are not reflected in the web app, the running version is for particular commit. There is same scenario if additional commit will be added.
I have checked the FastAPI files inside the docker container - there are the recent ones, so the running version should be up to date.
However, if I run `apt-get update` inside container, the recent version of web app will be available as expected. I have no idea what could be the reason that the code updates are not reflected instantly, also not sure how can I debug further.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.9


ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/"
ENV PORT=8000

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY ./requirements.txt /app/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./app /app
COPY ./documents /documents
```

Comment: try using the `--reload` flag when starting your gunicorn server